# Can I use printf() to convert hex to decimal and save the value?

Tags: c#

I know that I can convert a hex number to a decimal value using `printf(%u, num)` where `num` is a hex value. Can I use this value to also assign the converted number to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

To convert from decimal to hex do...

```
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

To convert from hex to decimal do either...

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

or

```
int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16);
```

Comment: Is convert part of specific package

Comment: @Shank19 no, It is System.Convert take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx